# WPF consuming much time to paste large texts to RichTextBox from clipboard

Tags: c#, wpf, richtextbox

I copied roughly a 200,000 length text to the Clipboard.

And I pasted it to RichTextBox by using shortcut key Ctrl V.

My pc couldn't load it..

But, when I pasted it to a TextBox, it worked well.

Can I ask you what problem is?

Here is my code snippet.

```
<RichTextBox Grid.Row="1" x:Name="에디터"  
             AcceptsTab="True" AcceptsReturn="True"  
             ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
 PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp="에디터_PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp"
             ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
            Margin="5"
             >
        <FlowDocument Name="editFlow" >
            <Paragraph>
                여기에 텍스트를 붙여 넣으세요
            </Paragraph>
        </FlowDocument>
    </RichTextBox>
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do it and you should not do it. WPF controls aren't designed to work with that kind of data(hence it freezes).Lets say even if you had succeded in adding that data in `RTB` the `scrollbars` would be useless as there would be very little data to display.Imagine the pains you will have when you have to locate a line in the text using scrollbar (it could take minutes...).

So the solution is you need to rethink what you are doing and maybe change your logic.

Comment: Thanks for reply. But, I tested it to another application, which uses rich textbox (http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/66054/A-Bindable-WPF-RichTextBox). Same texts containing 2598 Lines with a 200,000 length could load it by pressing short-cut Ctrl + V in a seconds. Anyway, Thanks. I need to find the other way.